# continueUserActivity not being called when Universal Link is launched, using AppsFlyer and React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-universal-links, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I'm working on adding Universal/Deep Linking to a React Native app, and it's also using the AppsFlyer React Native plugin / iOS SDK (however I believe this is not the issue). Whenever I click a universal link (an AppsFlyer OneLink), it launches the app but the `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` method simply isn't called. When I launch via the configured URL scheme, it works fine. I have added a `willContinueUserActivityWithType` method and this runs when the app is launched with the `NSUserActivity` type of `NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb` but after that it just launches the app as normal. This is the code in the AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <RNAppsFlyer.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

// ...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willContinueUserActivityWithType:(nonnull NSString *)userActivityType {
  if ([userActivityType isEqualToString:NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb]) {
    return YES; // using the xcode debbugger I can see it gets to here
  }
  return NO;
}

// handle Universal Links
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
  [[AppsFlyerAttribution shared] continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler]; // I don't think this is an issue. But I can provide more details about AppsFlyer if you need it
  return YES;
}

// other library/framework initialistion

@end
```

There is an issue on the Appsflyer github [here](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-react-native-plugin/issues/223), but none of the suggestions there have worked, plus apparently it's been fixed on the lastest framework version, which I am using (6.2.41). There is also an issue on the React Native github [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24429), but I have tried the suggestions (disabling remote JS debugging, release builds, etc) and nothing works; in fact in Release mode, `willContinueUserActivityWithType`doesn't get called at all. I continue to experiment here though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you as well, but my problem was that Firebase was overriding the continueUserActivity call with its own inside the `GLUAppDelegateSwizzler.m`.
The way I fixed it was by adding this to the info.plist file:

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry forgot to respond. Yes - the issue was similar. BlueShift's SDK, the Email Service Provider which my company use, is also integrated into our app. Their SDK was taking over some AppDelegate calls, including `continueUserActivity`. So your answer set me on the right course, thanks!